# How to increase ClickOnce download speed?

Tags: download, clickonce

I have created application and deployed it using ClickOnce it size is about 30MB, at first it take time about 2 - 3 hours on 128KB lease-line. Then I have enable file compression on IIS and download time is reduce to about 40 minutes.

I want to decrease download time to 10 - 20 minutes but I have no idea how to do that.

My solution has 4 projects a, b, c and d, two of these project have very large size (nearly 15 MB). I try to decompose these two project but it design is very tightly couple and I have no time to do that.

If anyone have idea or solution for this problem please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, about your only option is to find ways to compress/reduce the size of the projects themselves.  Although, if you really have 128KB, it should not have taken anywhere near 2-3 hours for 30MB, unless you are running other data across that connection at the same time.  As for the project itself, unless you can find a way to reduce the project size (you've already enabled compression in IIS) there's really nothing else open to you.

Answer (score 0):

A 128 kilobits per second connection should be able to upload a 30mb file in about 33 minutes so it sounds like your connection is OK.  You can possibly decrease the size of the file by getting rid of unnecessary dependencies (Visual Studio can perform this task for you, under Project Settings).  You probably won't be able to decrease the file size very much, however.

I think the most reasonable thing for you to do is to try and upgrade your connection. Even my crappy consumer-grade upload rate nearly quadruples your 128kbps line.

Good luck.